# Dimension of a vector space/ subspace with a finite basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, dimension-theory-algebra

Is the dimension of a vector space/subspace with a finite basis always the same as the number of elements in each vector and if so how can I derive that from the definition of a dimension?

Answer (score 4):

No, that the number of elements in the vector gives you the dimension of the space where your subspace lies. The dimension of the subspace is given by the number of linearly independent vectors in your generating set. To find those vectors, (called basis) you can write the vectors in a matrix form and convert to REF using elementary row operation along with some zero rows in the bottom. The number of non zero rows(read rank) will give you the dimension of the subspace.

Comment: Can you give an example of a vector space with a dimension that's different from the number of elements in each vector please?. I am confused because the dimension of all basis of a given vector space is the same and the standard basis obviously has the same number of vectors as the number of elements  in each vector.

Comment: Sure <1,0,0> and <0,1,0>. Let these be the generator of the subspace A. They clearly have 3 elements each, but the subspace A has a dimension of 2. Namely the xy plane embedded in space,as both the generators are linearly independent (note that they are not scalar multiple of each other).

Comment: No your assumption is false. Only a subset of the standard basis can generate your space like I have shown in my example loosely speaking. But if you want the standard basis completely, it might be the case you don't have a standard basis for your subspace, which precisely generates your space.

Comment: But by definition the cannot compose a basis for any vector space with 3-tuples in your example because the do not span such a vector space.

Comment: If you read the question carefully and compare with my example. Dimension of the xy plane embedded in space,l which is 2, with a finite basis like I mentioned in the example is not same as the number of elements in those vectors which is 3. Does it make sense now?

Answer (score 1):

"Elements" of a vector is not something that makes sense in an abstract vector space. It does make sense when considering vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$ (or more generally, $\Bbb{F}^n$ for some field $\Bbb{F}$), but not for more general vectors (e.g. functions).

Even if we restrict ourselves to vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$, the number of elements in a vector doesn't correspond necessarily to the dimension of the space. For example, if we consider the vector space
$$V = \{(x, y, z) \in \Bbb{R}^3 : x + y + z = 0\},$$
then each vector has exactly $3$ elements, but the space is $2$-dimensional (though, of course, it is a subspace of the $3$-dimensional space $\Bbb{R}^3$).

What makes more sense, instead of "elements", is "coordinates". Given any finite-dimensional space $V$ (i.e. one with a finite basis $B$), we can express vectors in $V$ as unique linear combinations of vectors in $B$. We can describe a vector $v \in V$ completely by the coefficients in the unique linear combination of vectors in $B$ that forms $v$. Since every basis has the same number of elements, every coordinate system has the same number of coordinates. This number is what we call the dimension of $V$.

So, in summary, "number of elements" of a vector doesn't make sense in general, but "number of coordinates" does make sense and is the very definition of dimension.

Comment: I guess I phrased my question wrong what I am trying to ask is: can I conclude that for any vector space for example V=Rⁿ over the field R the dimension of V would be n since every vector in V is an n-tuple?

Comment: @ORRAVRAHAM Sort of. The conclusion is valid, but the argument isn't. Yes, such a space has dimension $n$. To prove it, show that $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ is a basis for the space, where $e_i$ has a $1$ in the $i$th coordinate, but $0$ elsewhere. You can show that these vectors are linearly independent and spanning. This will show they are a basis, which makes $V$ $n$-dimensional by definition. The argument for this works, regardless of the field used (they all contain a $0$ and a $1$ at least).