# Confused about dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm confused cause my intuitive feeling is that if I have a vector (1,2,3) then it's 3D since it has a value for $x$, $y$, $z$, but it's only 1 vector so it can only span a line.

What is the dimension? Cause it's only a line so I feel like it shouldn't have a dimension of 3 but at the same time I wouldn't be able to write that line on a paper.

What's the right way to think about this?

Comment: You need to be more presize - if you take one point from $\mathbb{R}^3$, it can be even 0 dimension.

Comment: It's common to say "an $n$-dimensional vector" to mean, "a vector from $\mathbb R^n$", that is, it has length $n$.  The vector is not the thing that actually has the dimension, though.

Comment: See also the [related OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3737890/dimension-of-a-vector-space-subspace-with-a-finite-basis).

Answer (score 3):

The dimension is a concept we use for spaces or subspaces not for vectors.

More precisely, for a given subspace $S\subset \mathbb R^n $ the dimension of $S$ is, by [**definition**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_(vector_space)), equal to the number of vectors for a basis of $S$, i.e. the minimum number of independent vectors which span $S$.

Comment: So basically I can think of dimension as what it spans rather than what it lives in? (1,2,3), (3,2,1) lives in the 3D space but it can only span a plane which means that the dimension is 2

Comment: @frigolit_tarzan Yes of course, the dimension is a concept related to the subspace spanned by a set of vectors and it corresponds to the number of independent vectors among the given set (which is called a basis).

Comment: Does that mean  that if a vector in my vector space doesn't add anything to the dimension of the space, then it's a useless vector?

Comment: @frigolit_tarzan All vectors are important and any non zero vectors can be used as an element of a basis. What we can say is that if in a subspace $S$ we select a set of $n$ independent vectors which spans $S$ (i.e. a basis) any other vector can be expressed as a linear combination of these besis vectors.

Answer (score 2):

A vector, strictly speaking, does not have a dimension. The vector $v \equiv (1, 2,3)$ lives in 3D space since it has three components: the x-component, the y-component, the z-component.

We can speak of the line *along* the vector: $L \equiv \{ (\lambda \cdot 1, \lambda \cdot 2, \lambda \cdot 3) : \lambda \in \mathbb R \}$. A line is 1 dimensional because there's only one *direction*: the direction along $(1, 2, 3)$.

On the other hand, consider the $xy$ plane: $xy \equiv \{ (x, y, 0) : x, y \in \mathbb R \}$. Here, there are two directions, pointed by the x-axis: $(1, 0, 0)$ and the y-axis: $(0, 1, 0)$. So this is 2 dimensional.

Finally, the full vector space $\mathbb R^3$ is 3-dimensional because it contains three directions: $(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)$.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the number of vectors in a basis is an invariant.  This number is called the **dimension** of the vector space.